# Cassandra delete/update a row and get its previous value

Tags: cassandra, cql

How can I delete a row from Cassandra and get the value it had just before the deletion?

I could execute a `SELECT` and `DELETE` query in series, but how can I be sure that the data was not altered concurrently between the execution of those two queries?

I've tried to execute the `SELECT` and `DELETE` queries in a batch but that seems to be not allowed.

```
cqlsh:foo> BEGIN BATCH
       ...     SELECT * FROM data_by_user WHERE user = 'foo';
       ...     DELETE FROM data_by_user WHERE user = 'foo';
       ... APPLY BATCH;
SyntaxException: line 2:4 mismatched input 'SELECT' expecting K_APPLY (BEGIN BATCH    [SELECT]...)
```

---

In my use case I have one main table that stores data for items. And I've build several tables that allow to lookup items based on those informations.
If I delete an item from the main table, I must also remove it from the other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE items (id text PRIMARY KEY, owner text, liking_users set<text>, ...);

CREATE TABLE owned_items_by_user (user text, item_id text, PRIMARY KEY ((user), item_id));
CREATE TABLE liked_items_by_user (user text, item_id tect, PRIMARY KEY ((user), item_id));
...
```

I'm afraid the tables might contain wrong data if I delete an item and at the same time someone e.g. hits the like button of that same item.

- The `deleteItem` method execute a `SELECT` query to fetch the current row of the item from the main table
- The `likeItem` method that gets executed at the same times runs an `UPDATE` query and inserts the item into the `owned_items_by_user`, `liked_items_by_user`, ... tables. This happens after the `SELECT` statement was executed and the `UPDATE` query is executed before the `DELETE` query.
- The `deleteItem` method deletes the items from the `owned_items_by_user`, `liked_items_by_user`, ... tables based on the data just retrieved via the `SELECT` statement. This data does not yet contain the just added like. The item is therefore deleted, but the just added like remains in the `liked_items_by_user` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a select beforehand, then do a lightweight transaction on the delete to ensure that the data still looks exactly like it did when you selected. If it does, you know the latest state before you deleted. If it does not, keep retrying the whole procedure until it sticks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that's what I've ended up with. I'm just a little afraid that this may not be very performant.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do a `SELECT` query inside a batch statement. If you read the docs [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlBatch.html), only insert, update, and delete statements can be used.

What you're looking for is atomicity on the execution, but batch statements are not going to be the way forward. If the data has been altered, your worst case situation is zombies, or data that could reappear.

Cassandra uses a grade period mechanism to deal with this, you can find the details [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDeletes.html). If for whatever reason, this is critical to your business logic, the "best" thing you can do in this situation is to increase the consistency level, or restructure the read pattern at application level to not rely on perfect atomicity, whichever the right trade off is for you. So either you give up some of the performance, or tune down the requirement.

In practice, `QUORUM` should be more than enough to satisfy most situations most of the time. Alternatively, you can do an `ALL`, and you pay the performance penalty, but that means all replicas for the given `foo` partition key will have to acknowledge the write both in the `commitlog` and the `memtable`. Note, this still means a `flush` from the commitlog will need to happen before the delete is `complete`, but you can tune the consistency to the level you require.

You don't have atomicity in the SQL sense, but depending on throughput it's unlikely that you will need it(touch wood).

TLDR:

```
USE CONSISTENCY ALL;
DELETE FROM data_by_user WHERE user = 'foo';
```

That should do the trick. The error you're seeing now is basically the ANTLR3 Grammar parser for CQL 3, which is not designed to accept to SELECT queries inside batches simply because they are not supported, you can see that **[here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/src/antlr/Parser.g#L532)**.

Comment: I've attached an example scenario where my issue occures to the questions. Do you have any idea how a workaround may look for that case? I though about materialized views, but I don't know how to create a materialized view for a `set<text>`.

Comment: @Aki Do the cross table delete in a batch then, you can delete from 2 tables like that.